# Simulating Key Press On DOM element

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dom-events, webview2

I am trying to automate a web entry form with C# using WebView2.

Web entry form has three DOM Elements: Input (UserName/Password) and Entry Button (disabled).

If you enter value to input areas by keyboard (manually) Entry Button is enabled. But sending Java Scripts to set value of input boxes do not make this button enabled. Of course it is a guard to disable automation of this page...

Is there a way to make Entry Button enabled with java script?

Page image is below:

[image: Form Entry]

Comment: `document.getElementById('EntryButton').disabled = false;`

Comment: @PoulBak it does not effect button anyway, I have added image of Script Result by WebView2 tools, thanks...

Comment: Don't add text as images, add the text in a code formatted block! Have you tried to call the button's `click()` method after the change?

Comment: to click button, first it has to be enabled!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that site owner has arranged actions for 'Entry Button' will be enabled only by keystroke. Guard against automation...

To simulate keystroke action you may use below code for each DOM element:

```
document.getElementById('USERNAME').focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'YourName');
document.getElementById('PASSWORD').focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Password');
document.getElementById('ENTRY').click();
```

This will activate 'Entry Button' by pasting your data like keystrokes...

Comment: I can call this solution genius, thanks a lot

Comment: case data box has previous value anyway, apply this to clear old value: `document.getElementById('USERNAME').value = ''`.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I've just released [WebView2.DevTools.Dom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebView2.DevTools.Dom/) to [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/amaitland). It's free for anyone to use.

More details and examples in the [Readme](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom#webview2-devtools-dom)

```cs
 await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
 
// Add using WebView2.DevTools.Dom; to access the CreateDevToolsContextAsync extension method
 await using var devToolsContext = await webView2Browser.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();

// Get element by Id
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
var userName = await devtoolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#USERNAME");

//Type text in an input field
await userName.TypeAsync("myusername");

var password = await devtoolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#PASSWORD");

//Type text in an input field
await password.TypeAsync("mypassword");

var button = await devtoolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#BUTTON");

//Click The element
await button.ClickAsync();
```

This will simulate both key presses and mouse move/clicks.