# How do I get the string passed to be recognised as text in the fields?

Tags: c#, webview2

I have managed to enter the username and password in the appropriate fields on the website, but for reasons unknown to me they are displayed but not recognised as entered text. This means that the "Login" button is not activated. Please help me to solve this problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

        }
        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await webViewKB.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
            webViewKB.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded;
            webViewKB.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += new EventHandler<CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs>(InputUser);
            webViewKB.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += new EventHandler<CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs>(InputPassword);
        }

        private async void InputUser(object sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
        {
            await webViewKB.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementsByClassName('MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-input css-mnn31')[0].value = '{user}'; ");
            await webViewKB.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('signInUsername').value = '{user}'; ");
        }
        private async void InputPassword(object sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
        {
            await webViewKB.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementsByClassName('MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-input css-mnn31')[1].value = '{pw}'; ");
            await webViewKB.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('signInPassword').value = '{pw}'; ");
        }
        private async void CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded(object sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs e)
        {
            await webViewKB.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"document.getElementsByClassName('MuiButtonBase-root MuiFab-root MuiFab-circular MuiFab-sizeLarge MuiFab-primary css-8yw3ib')[0].click();");
            await webViewKB.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"document.getElementsByClassName('MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButtonBase-root css-ou8xsw css-150zpdr')[0].click();");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see username and password values are being entered in the textboxes?

Comment: @Chetan Yes, isee the entered values. If I fill the fields manually then the login button turns blue and I can press it. If the values comes from the code, the username and password are displayed in the corresponding field but the login button remains grey.

Comment: Looks like there is some logic on the page which expects keys to be pressed for button to be enabled. Setting text box vlaues is not same as key pressing

Comment: @Chetan Your advice has already helped me a little. I was able to simulate the clicking of the field with `await webViewKB.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('signInPassword').focus()");` The corresponding field is now selected and filled, but deleted again when it jumps to the next field. Idea?

Comment: I found the solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328256/simulating-key-press-on-dom-element)

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for websites to validate input fields requiring keyboard/osk input in an attempt to deter bots. You can workaround this by simulating key presses.

For this you can use [WebView2.DevTools.Dom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebView2.DevTools.Dom/) which is available via [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/amaitland). It's free for anyone to use.

More details and examples in the [Readme](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom#webview2-devtools-dom)

```cs
private async void CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded(object sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs e)
{
    // Add using WebView2.DevTools.Dom; to access the CreateDevToolsContextAsync extension method
    await using var devToolsContext = await webViewKB.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();
    
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
    var userName = await devtoolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#signInUsername");

    //Type text in an input field
    await userName.TypeAsync($"{user}");
    
    var password = await devtoolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#signInPassword");

    //Type text in an input field
    await password.TypeAsync($"{pw}");
    
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
    // Select button via id, class, etc 
    var button = await devtoolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync(".MuiButtonBase-root .MuiFab-root .MuiFab-circular .MuiFab-sizeLarge .MuiFab-primary .css-8yw3ib");

    //Click The element
    await button.ClickAsync();
}
```

This will simulate both key presses and mouse move/clicks.

I'd advocate for removing the multiple event handlers, it's unnecessary and complicates your code.